# Building D3D11On12 project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, directx-11, directx-12

I have a c++ application that utilizes microsofts desktop duplication.  The application works fine when i force my computer to run utilizing the integrated GPU.  However when using Nvidia GPU it fails.   After some digging i found that the desktop duplication isnt compatible with DirectX12.

I found the following microsoft github project that creates a bridge between directx 11 and 12.
https://github.com/microsoft/D3D11On12

I am not that familar with c++ and cmake files but.
When i pulled the project down and ran CMake on it it creates a series of projects that with dependencies and my understanding is a dll when built.

my CMake
[image: Cmake configurations]

When i open the project and attempt to build it i get compile errors from the d3d11on12 project files indicating that it cant find .h files located in the d3d12translationlayer project.
When i look at the D3D11On12 references it doesnt contain anything and if i add a reference to the translationLayer I get what i'm assuming is a visual studio's auto generated error for the Full Path.  If I open up ALL_BUILD and look at its reference it successfully adds the d3d12translationlayer and its path is correct.

[image]

Any help getting this to compile would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed the latest SDK as indicated in the doc: https://github.com/microsoft/D3D11On12#building "At the time of publishing, the D3D11On12 and D3D12TranslationLayer require insider versions of the SDK and WDK." https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewWDK PS: you don't have to build it yourself, there's a version that comes with Windows (\windows\system32\d3d11on12.dll)

Comment: Yes i have the insider versions of the SDK and WDK.  But didnt even realize the dll existed.  They should update the github readme to indicate that it exist in latest Windows.  This helps a lot thanks. Mine is located in C:\Windows\WinSxS\wow64_microsoft-windows-directx-direct3d11on12_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.844_none_e42390dfdaaa4b3d\d3d11on12.dll

Comment: If you can post your comment as the solution I will accept it as it is a work around that I find most people would likely find more useful than building it themselves.

Comment: It's indicated here: https://github.com/microsoft/D3D11On12#what-can-you-do-with-this you should post an answer